# Unity C# "The name 'mathf' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working through a Unity intro course using C# scripting, and when I try to use the "Mathf" utility I get the error:

> The name 'mathf' does not exist in the current context

I am just adding a C# script (Sep23) onto an empty object in the scene. For reference I am following Sebastian Lague's demo: https://youtu.be/zQPyGjPUDVE

My code is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sep23 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print ("start");
        float dist = GetDistBtwTwoPoints(5, 1, 10, 7);
        print(dist);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    float GetDistBtwTwoPoints(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        float dX = x2-x1;
        float dY = y2-y1;
        float dstSqrd = dX*dX + dY*dY;
        float dst = mathf.sqrt(dstSqrd);
        return dst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use capital M. "Mathf.sqrt(dstSqrd);"

Comment: @DawidWawrzynczyk Thank you, that resolved the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capitalization matters.

```
float dst = Mathf.Sqrt(dstSqrd);
```